# How can I display an array model property as a list in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this array property in my model and would like to see it in my view as a dropdown list. Here's the array property:

```
public string[] weekDays = new string[5] { "monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };

public string[] WeekDays
{
    get { return weekDays; }
}
```

I've look for hours with no simple explanation or examples.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved it.

```
@{
    var wekdys = new Enrollment();
    @Html.DropDownList("weekDays", wekdys.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString() }))
}
```

this allows me to have a DropDownList outside of the foreach loop

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DropDownList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx) html helper.

```
Html.DropDownList("weekDays",
                  Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s }))
```

If you want to read the selected value you can use [DropDownListFor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834953) helper.

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedWeekDay, //a property to assign the value
                              Model.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s, Value = s }))
```

Comment: This worked: @Html.DropDownList("weekDays", item.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString() }))

Comment: This worked: @Html.DropDownList("weekDays", item.WeekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString() })) but only in the table inside the foreach loop but not outside of the loop.I can't access the weekDays property using item.WeekDays.Select or Model.Enrollments.Select.  How can I make the dropdown list outside of the foreach loop?

Comment: You can still access Model instance inside the lambda expression if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes I in can do this s=> new SelectListItem{}... because I have access to the model properties only in the foreach loop?